# Parse a large string literal in JS with regex into object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, object

So, I'm new to programming, but I'm trying to learn JavaScript. Currently I'm working on a project where I'm trying to parse a large text file (the 154 sonnets of Shakespeare found [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1041/pg1041.txt)) into an object array, in the following data structure:

```
var obj = {
property 1: [ 'value 1',
     'value 2',
    ], 
property 2: [ 'value 1',
     'value 2',
    ],
```

etc., where roman numerals represent object properties and each line of the sonnet represents a value in each property's array.

I must use regular expressions to parse through the text file. So far I've been searching for the correct regexp to demarcate the text, but I don't know if I'm going about this the right way. Ultimately I want to create a drop down menu where each value in the list is a sonnet.

Edit: I'm actually now taking the source text from this url: http://pizzaboys.biz/xxx/sonnets.php

and doing the same thing as above, but instead of doing a $get I've put the text into a variable...

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = new SonnetizerArray();
});

function SonnetizerArray(){
    this.data = [];
    var rawText = "text from above link"
    var rx = /^\\n[CDILVX]/$\\n/g;

    var array_of_sonnets = rawText.exec(rx);
    for (var i = 0; i < array_of_sonnets.length; i ++){
        var s = $.split(array_of_sonnets[i]);
        if (s.length > 0) this.data.push(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, show what you've found/tried so far. You might be close, you might not; we have no idea your attempts.

Comment: just added it into the original.

Answer (score 5):

## Description

This regex will parse the text into a roman numeral and body. The body can then be split on the new line `\n`.

`^\s+\b([CDMLXVI]{1,12})\b(?:\r|\n|$).*?(?:^.*?)(^.*?)(?=^\s+\b([MLXVI]{1,12})\b(?:\r|\n|$)|\Z)`

[image]

## Capture Groups

Group 0 get the entire matching section

1. gets the roman numeral
2. gets the body of the section, not including the roman numeral

## Javascript Code Example:

Sample text [pulled from your link](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1041/pg1041.txt)

```
  VII

  Lo! in the orient when the gracious light
  Lifts up his burning head, each under eye
  Doth homage to his new-appearing sight,


  VIII

  Music to hear, why hear'st thou music sadly?
  Sweets with sweets war not, joy delights in joy:
  Why lov'st thou that which thou receiv'st not gladly,
  Or else receiv'st with pleasure thine annoy?


  IX

  Is it for fear to wet a widow's eye,
  That thou consum'st thy self in single life?
  Ah! if thou issueless shalt hap to die,
  The world will wail thee like a makeless wife;
```

Example code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var re = /^\s+\b([MLXVI]{1,12})\b(?:\r|\n|$).*?(?:^.*?)(^.*?)(?=^\s+\b([MLXVI]{1,12})\b(?:\r|\n|$)|\Z)/;
  var sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  var results = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var matches = re.exec(sourcestring); matches != null; matches = re.exec(sourcestring)) {
    results[i] = matches;
    for (var j=0; j<matches.length; j++) {
      alert("results["+i+"]["+j+"] = " + results[i][j]);
    }
    i++;
  }
</script>
```

Sample output

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>   VII

  Lo! in the orient when the gracious light
  Lifts up his burning head, each under eye
  Doth homage to his new-appearing sight,

            [1] => 

  VIII

  Music to hear, why hear'st thou music sadly?
  Sweets with sweets war not, joy delights in joy:
  Why lov'st thou that which thou receiv'st not gladly,
  Or else receiv'st with pleasure thine annoy?

            [2] => 

  IX

  Is it for fear to wet a widow's eye,
  That thou consum'st thy self in single life?
  Ah! if thou issueless shalt hap to die,
  The world will wail thee like a makeless wife;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => VII
            [1] => VIII
            [2] => IX
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
  Lo! in the orient when the gracious light
  Lifts up his burning head, each under eye
  Doth homage to his new-appearing sight,

            [1] => 
  Music to hear, why hear'st thou music sadly?
  Sweets with sweets war not, joy delights in joy:
  Why lov'st thou that which thou receiv'st not gladly,
  Or else receiv'st with pleasure thine annoy?

            [2] => 
  Is it for fear to wet a widow's eye,
  That thou consum'st thy self in single life?
  Ah! if thou issueless shalt hap to die,
  The world will wail thee like a makeless wife;
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIII
            [1] => IX
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

## Roman numeral validation

The above expression only tests the roman numeral string is composed of roman numeral characters, it doesn't actually validate the number is valid. If you need to validate the roman numeral is correctly formatted too, then you could use this expression.

`^\s+\b(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))\b(?:\r|\n|$).*?(?:^.*?)(^.*?)(?=^\s+\b([MLXVI]{1,12})\b(?:\r|\n|$)|\Z)`

[image]

Comment: I suspect you're attempting to paste the sample text into directly into the program as a multi line string. If so then you'll need to include a new line character in string and end each line with a `\` which tells javascript to continue to the next line.

Comment: To show the expression does work try have a look at a working demo http://regex101.com/r/fK4rR3, or this with roman numeral validation http://regex101.com/r/cM6uR9

Comment: I'm still confused about how to actually create the data structure I wrote above, i.e., an object with 154 properties and 154 arrays with 14 values each, from a regular expression.

Comment: I would first convert the roman numeral to a decimal because it's easier to sort, using something like http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-roman-numeral-converter. Then creating the multidimensional array is easy as http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/162679-how-define-array-array